# Check if selected microphone is muted or not with web audio api

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

By using the following, we can prompt the user to select their preferred media input device with audio and video source constraints (currently only interested in Chrome support).

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then((stream) => {
    console.log(stream);
  });
```

Anyone know if there is an exposed API to detect if the user-selected input device is currently muted or not? The input device would be either an onboard microphone, external mic, or software defined microphone that shows in the system as a hardware device.

Answer (score 9):

You can check property `.muted` `Boolean` value of each `MediaStreamTrack` by iterating the array returned by `MediaStream` [`.getAudioTracks()`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediastream-getaudiotracks) method, or by selecting the `MediaStreamTrack` by index from the array.

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then(stream => {
    console.log("MediaStreamTrack muted:", stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can also utilize `mute` and `unmute` `MediaStreamTrack` events.

Comment: This doesn't seem to reflect the actual muted state of the microphone in Chrome 57 (Windows 10), even when selecting a specific non-`Default` microphone by `deviceId`.

Comment: @ChrisHunt The `volume` property of `contraints` can also be set. See [Capabilities, constraints, and settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints). How was microphone muted? Can you describe how to reproduce case? Have you attached `onmute`, `onunmute` events to the `MediaStreamTrack`?

Comment: First identify enabled microphone under Tray > Sound icon context menu > Recording Devices > Audio. Use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to identify the `deviceId` for the device with the same label. Use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { deviceId: '...' } })` to select the device. Verify `track = stream.getTracks()[0]` matches the device and check `track.muted`. Mute the microphone via the "Levels" tab for the specific device in the "Recording Devices" dialog. Check `track.muted` and see that it has not changed.

Comment: Where is `Tray`? `DevTools`? Have not tried chrome 57. Was not aware that chrome 57 was available. Tried at chromium 52. If you record the stream, is playback of recorded stream mute?

Comment: Tray refers to the Windows tray area where the sound settings are available via context menu on the sound icon. I used the demo available [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) to validate that no sound is recorded when the device is muted but it still doesn't appear that the muted property of the device (at least when done through the OS recording device settings) is reflected in the `muted` property of the stream. FYI the MediaCapture and Stream Spec backs you up, so this might just be a bug or some problem of mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131388/discussion-between-chris-hunt-and-guest271314).

Comment: @ChrisHunt Have you found a solution to get the actual mute state from the OS? I've managed to reproduce your issue.