# MediaDevices : Is it possible to detect if a device's microphone is muted?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, microphone

As the title say, I'm using javascript to detect if a browser's / device's microphone is muted or not. I am currently using webRTC which is mainly from the code below.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

So, is it possible to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309852/2016831

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if selected microphone is muted or not with web audio api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309682/check-if-selected-microphone-is-muted-or-not-with-web-audio-api)